# Item with "View Only" permissions in library is downloadable

Tags: 2010, permissions, library, video

I have a video file in a Sharepoint2010 Site Assets library which is embedded in a web part.
This video on the page with the web part should be playable by everyone in our intranet, but not downloadable from the Site Assets library.

I have set the permissions for Authenticated Users in the Site Assets library to View Only, but the users are still able to download the file.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this with a very simple workaround.

- I gave all users view only permissions
- Then i changed in the asset list to edit mode
- Select the web part with the specific list and click "Edit Web Part"
- In the Advanced settings under "Target Audiences" enter all the users/groups that should still be able to view the items in the list

After finishing this, the video is still playing fine in my web part, but not visible in the Site Assets library.

Also see this [link](http://www.snatchexcel.com/hide-send-to-option-download-a-copy-option-for-visitor-groups/#.VCFFDJRv5KA) for a better description.

Comment: the link no longer works unfortunately